# Selection Of Model---prediction of cpu usage

Tags: machine-learning, time-series, forecasting

Currently I am working on a project and was hoping to ask this question as a sanity check as I am still very new to this area.

Currently I am collecting CPU usage values for machines at a 1s interval and am attempting to make a prediction based on these values for a future value. Due to the project, I was hoping to take the last 2 minute window and use these 120 values when making my prediction.

I am currently mainly considering two main approaches, and was hoping for some insight into this.

I had hoped to either use a arima model for the predictions or using a sparse linear regression.

I have research a bit and found the arima model and am unsure if it is the best choice, but worry the spare linear regression will not account for things such as any lag in the timeseries and the fact it does not treat the data as timeseries data which I also believe could be benifical.

My worry with arima is most examples seem to be related to timeseries spanning months / weeks and am aware I am ignorant to its uses

So my question is would this model (arima) be appropriate for this implementation, and if not, where would be a good place to start my research on this as there seems to be a lot of models related to this area.

Edit: the predictions would be for 5 seconds in the future.

Edit2: Example of metric data collected: https://pastebin.com/zyHaJ4vb

Comment: what's your forecast horizon?

Comment: The hope was for predictions to be ~5 seconds in the future.

Comment: ARIMA should work, maybe ARMA, actually. I'd be surprised if you beat it with anything else

Comment: Thank you, glad to hear my general direction was not too far off, will continue researching ARMA and ARIMA!

Comment: if you show an example of your data, it would help, e.g. 10 minutes of CPU tulization

Comment: The data will be 120 utilization values as a percentage which should not exceed 100% (but may). The data would be recieved as timeseries info with each datapoint containing the time occured and the value at this time so would look like: [[0, 2][1 2.5]]

Comment: @Aksakalalmostsurelybinary apologies, for the poor example data, I have updated the post with an export of some of my data linked in a pastebin. the values shown are all very low as there is no load but it is representative of the data i believe